# Сортировка в с++

Tags: c++

Недавно начал програмировать на с++ и возник вопрос.
Написал программу которая показывает список учеников и их оценки. Создал два вектора для имени и оценки. Интересует вопрос как отсортировать список по убыванию оценок студентов (сначала самый высокий бал). Затем вывести все имена и оценки в отсортированном виде.(отсортировать могу,но не могу связать имя и оценку)`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
  vector<string> name_of_students;
  vector<double> marks_of_students;
void name() {
   cout << "Type the name of student ";
   string name;
   cin >> name;
   name_of_students.push_back(name);
}
int mark() {
  cout << "Type the mark of this student";
  int mark;
  cin >> mark;
  marks_of_students.push_back(mark);
  return mark;
}

 void main(){
   cout << "How many student in your class?";
   int number_of_students;
   cin >> number_of_students;
   for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
    name();
    mark();
}
 cout << "Number of students is " << name_of_students.size() << " 
 people.\n";
 for (int i = 0; i < name_of_students.size(); i++) {
    cout << name_of_students[i] << " " << marks_of_students[i] << "marks\n";

}
keep_window_open();

}
```

Comment: Может вместо двух векторов один вектор структур? А потом сортировка через `std::sort` (в гугле есть примеры, как сортировать по определенному полю структуры).

Comment: я не очень и понял метод структур, можно ли описать в этом коде?

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно? Делается что-то вроде `struct Student {string name; double mark;};`. Потом делается вместо нескольких - один вектор из `struct Student`.

Comment: сейчас попробую запилить по такому типу.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких вещей принято вместо использования двух объектов, использовать один. Тобишь список оценок - это, по сути, один объект, в котором есть список учеников, каждому из которых присвоены оценки. Таким образом, лучше сделать структуру (на самом деле есть вариант получше, но это сложнее, я напишу ниже). Что-то вроде:

```
class Student {
   private:
   std::string name_;
   unsigned short digit_;
   public:
    //сдесь конструктор и функции
}
```

В результате вам нужно будет создать один вектор, а не два. А дальше начинается интересное. В стандартной библиотеке есть функция `sort`, которая принимает итератор на начало, конец и предикат. Если что-то из этого не знакомо - что ж, придется познакомится.

Итак, далее пишем:

```
std::vector<Student> list;
...
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), 
  [](const Studeng &a, const Student &b){return a.digit() < b.digit();});
```

Метод `digit`, я думаю, сами сможете реализовать. Кстати, если не знаете что за конструкция приведена - это лямбда. Можно поступить по другом: определить `operator<` в классе соответствующим образом, и тогда предикат можно опустить. Так, кстати говоря, почти любой контейнер можно отсортировать (кроме тех, которые сами элементы упорядочивают).

Выше я писал о лучшем методе: это использовани `map`, но думаю, это будет еще сложновато для вас. Вкратце, для использования `map` (или, если использовать эту структуру, то можно и `set` обойтись) обязательно нужно указать либо `operator <` в классе, либо при инициализации контейнера указать предикат. В этих классах, благодоря древовидной структуре, элементы сами упорядочиваются.

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Я бы для упрощения даже не заморачивался с приватными полями.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну раз кодить, то хоть не по черному)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, для чего использовать классы и при этом не переопределять operator<, но зато использовать лямбды, где это совершенно не нужно.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker окей, раз вам не понятно то давайте так: вы определили `operator<` для вашего класса `Student` - что он будет сравнивать? Если оценки - окей, нет проблем. А если имена (что, имхо, более логично, ведь это студент имеет оценку, а не оценка студента), то как вы будете использовать данную функцию? Я достаточно понятно объяснил зачем тут лямбда?

Comment: Окей, раз вам не понятно, то давайте так: зачем тут изначально использовать классы? Потому что С++? Для хранения пары значений разного (или одинакового) типа можно использовать std::pair, где для вас давно реализовали и operator< и operator>, которые вы можете передавать в std::sort, как функтор. Для чего плодить классы - так и не особо понятно, инкапсуляция? Данный тип данных предназначен для хранения информации и только.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker слушайте, а вы мой ответ читали вообще? Я сразу написал, что этот способ не лучший, но простой для новичка, а ниже написал про `map` и `set`. И, если вы не вкурсе, то обычно студенты имеуют чуть больше оценок, чем одна - так что `pair<std::string, int>` не подойдет, вторым параметром должен быть какой-нибудь контейнер. Но раз так, то начерта использовать голые пары, если есть `map`? И еще раз, обратите внимание: это все было, есть и будет в ответе.

Comment: Если вы не в курсе, то в pair можно хранить и контейнеры в том числе. Автор явно сказал - есть студент и одна оценка, для чего вы придумываете "несколько оценок" за автора - не ясно. Вы указали, что это не лучший способ, но зато понятный, при этом использовав классы, а не структуры, на что я и спросил: "зачем?". На что вы яро пытаетесь что-то доказать, явно пытаясь выставить себя умнее, чем собеседник всякими "если вам не понятно" и "если вы не в курсе". Это уже не обсуждение ответа, а токсичное выяснение отношений после простого вопроса "зачем тут классы и лямбды".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я не понимаю что вас не устраивает: вы написали, что не понимаете почему я написал именно так - я вам ответил почему, а вы продолжаете цепляться непонятно за что! И по поводу pair, может вы и не в курсе, но в map храняться именно пары! Где вы увидели, что я писал, что там нельзя хранить контейнеры - я не знаю. Это вы мне тут писали, что для пар реализваны operator < и > - вот сами себе и ответьте, как это будет работать с контейнером. Что касается про "раз вам не понятно" - во первых вы сами написали, что вам не понятно, во-вторых вы и сами так писали...

Comment: @RiotBr3aker и на последок: объясните мне пожалуйста разницу между класмом и струтурой - будете смеяться, но я, видимо совсем дурак, всегда думал, что структура от класса отличается только тем, что по умолчании в стуктуре члены находятся в public, а в классе - в private. Но вам видимо больше известно, раз вы тут так ополчились - расскажите пожалуйста, не ходить же мне дураком до конца жизни..